# Handle NSFetchedResultsController DidChangeSection IOS Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm writing an implementation to handle `NSFetchResultsController` DidChangeSection but I got this strange warning

Here is my method

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [stampsTableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [stampsTableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}
```

And the warning is pic below. How can I resolve the warning?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add default to handle other case

```
switch (type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        break;
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```